# openssl - generating rsa key pair - public key

Tags: openssl

I am trying to generate RSA 1024 key pair (public/private) using the following command

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
```

In the server.key file, only RSA private block is there, so where does the public key go ?

Comment: OT: You might want to generate a longer key. 1024 [might get broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size#Key_size_and_encryption_system).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RSA private key format includes all the public elements. When you get the private key you really have both the private and public key.

This is described in [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) (the leading RSA standard); private key format is an encoded ASN.1 structure which contains:

```
  RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      version           Version,
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
      privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
      prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
      prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
      exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
      exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
      coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
      otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
  }
```

The public key really consists in the *modulus* and *public exponent*, which are both in the private key structure, as shown above.

---

Now your question might be: "what if I want the public key 'alone' ?"

OpenSSL lives in and by the X.509 world. In [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), public key don't exist as stand-alone values; and there is no standard file format for lone public keys. An application is supposed to use public keys that it found in *certificates*. This is quite apparent in the [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) protocol (which is the primary support goal of OpenSSL): when the client sends its public key, it sends it as a certificate. Therefore, if you want the public key in a file, arrange for it to be stored in a certificates (possibly self-signed). The OpenSSL [req](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#) sub-command, with the `-x509` flag, can help.

Of course, every rule has exceptions, so there is *also* a method to get the public key "only" from the private key; this is what @uwotm8 shows in his answer. However, the resulting public key, which will look like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDzYY+BpIuKouSnoemSwHwC25uW
Xc0zX1gl8NtG5UQP2U4Lda0s5XbBJm4O2W+RkOgR1f1d5cGOXRPd6Q9ntw3MYQv6
ubsMRZUaOT4vCpykWfPi/VfsQEPlWHw2pulYAyumx/sw8tX5i9NC2e2bY4eWwo22
BELyXpNdoGozSje8PQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

is not really usable anywhere, because this is a non-standard format.

(Technically this is a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` element as it appears in an X.509 certificate, but it is not supposed to appear outside of an X.509 certificate.)

Comment: It's at least compatible with `X509EncodedKeySpec` and the `"RSA"` `KeyFactory` in Java. Don't know about others. After PEM decoding, e.g. using Bouncy Castle, of course.

Answer (score 5):

The public key needs to be derived from the private key. Try this command:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -pubout
```